# How do I iterate through array in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I need to iterate through managed data disks in Azure Resource Graph Explorer (https://preview.portal.azure.com/). My query is below but it returns JSON array, I need to extract name of disk and type of storage account which is being used (sample JSON return is below). So I'd like to see on screen grouping by machine name, disk name and then storage account type. My current query is below but obviously it does not work due to return of JSON

```
where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachines' |
extend disks = properties.storageProfile.dataDisks |
project name, disks
```

Same JSON output

```
[
    {
        "name": "COMP02_DDisk1",
        "createOption": "Attach",
        "diskSizeGB": 400,
        "managedDisk": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/5f5c5be9-77d4db790171/resourceGroups/BRAZILSOUTHDB/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/COMP02_DDisk1",
            "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS"
        },
        "caching": "None",
        "toBeDetached": false,
        "lun": 0,
        "writeAcceleratorEnabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "COMP02_DDisk2",
        "createOption": "Attach",
        "diskSizeGB": 400,
        "managedDisk": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/5f5c5be9-77d4db790171/resourceGroups/BRAZILSOUTHDB/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/COMP02_DDisk2",
            "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS"
        },
        "caching": "None",
        "toBeDetached": false,
        "lun": 1,
        "writeAcceleratorEnabled": false
    }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in such cases, it's usually helpful to use `mv-expand` to expand the array and then apply the dynamic-property accessors foreach record.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator

example:

```
print d = dynamic([
    {
        "name": "COMP02_DDisk1",
        "createOption": "Attach",
        "diskSizeGB": 400,
        "managedDisk": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/5f5c5be9-77d4db790171/resourceGroups/BRAZILSOUTHDB/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/COMP02_DDisk1",
            "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS"
        },
        "caching": "None",
        "toBeDetached": false,
        "lun": 0,
        "writeAcceleratorEnabled": false
    },
    {
        "name": "COMP02_DDisk2",
        "createOption": "Attach",
        "diskSizeGB": 400,
        "managedDisk": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/5f5c5be9-77d4db790171/resourceGroups/BRAZILSOUTHDB/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/COMP02_DDisk2",
            "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS"
        },
        "caching": "None",
        "toBeDetached": false,
        "lun": 1,
        "writeAcceleratorEnabled": false
    }
])
| mv-expand d
| project d.name, d.managedDisk.storageAccountType
```

which will output:

```
| d_name        | d_managedDisk_storageAccountType |
|---------------|----------------------------------|
| COMP02_DDisk1 | Premium_LRS                      |
| COMP02_DDisk2 | Premium_LRS                      |
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like Azure Resource Graph explorer does not support mv-expand (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/concepts/query-language)

Comment: it appears so. sorry, i got thrown by the `kusto` and `azure-data-explorer` tags :-(

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are doing good .

You can try this way also, First i found networksecuritygroups from entire collection and later filtered **defaultSecurityRules** which is again an array.
After collecting it using **mvexpand** in local variable *rules* you should be able to fetch the desired after applying.

```
 where type =~ "microsoft.network/networksecuritygroups"
| mvexpand rules = properties.defaultSecurityRules
| where rules.properties.destinationAddressPrefix =~ "*"
```

You can also refer given below link and wish it will help you also.